# Animating (scrolling) one ViewGroup blocks unrelated Views from animation until finished

Tags: android, android-animation, kotlin

#### View hierarchy:

```
[0/6] View (first view in layout)
...
[2/6] RecyclerView
... 
RecyclerView's children views
...
[6/6] View (point of interest, on top)
```

#### Goal:

I need to slide in (using fast-out-slow-in interpolator)
last View (which happens to be custom toolbar) in my hierarchy when `RecyclerView` is scrolled suffiently high and slide it out when `RecyclerView` is suffiently low. Effect similar to 
sliding title header at https://material.io/.

#### Problem:

Toolbar's animations - (view is initially hidden) to show:

```
title_bar.animate()
         .setInterpolator(FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
         .setDuration(500)
         .setStartDelay(0)
         .translationY(0f)
         .start()
```

and hide it:

```
title_bar.animate()
         .setInterpolator(FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
         .setDuration(500)
         .setStartDelay(0)
         .translationY(someValue)
         .start()
```

The problem is that animations won't run until `RecyclerView`'s scrolling stops (key-up).

I suspect animations are queued in FIFO somehow and pending until scrolling stops. I don't understand why that may be the case since two views are completely independent and `RecyclerView` is below my Toolbar.

#### The Twist

This works perfectly fine:

```
title_bar.animate()
         .setInterpolator(FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
         .setDuration(0) // <-- duration is zero
         .setStartDelay(0)
         .translationY(someValue)
         .start()
```

i.e. animation is fired right away (maybe it's equivalent to `title_bar.translationY = someValue`?)

So, what is happening here exactly?

Comment: Your twist was exactly what I needed. Thanks